# AngularJS + Karma + Ng-html2js => Failed to instantiate module ...html

Tags: templates, angularjs, testing, directive, karma-runner

I can't make Karma working for directives that have external templates.

Here is my karma configuration file :

```js
preprocessors: {
    'directives/loading/templates/loading.html': 'ng-html2js'
},

files: [
    ...
    'directives/loading/templates/loading.html',
]

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    prependPrefix: '/app/'
},
```

In the directive file :

```js
...
templateUrl: '/app/directives/loading/templates/loading.html'
...
```

In the spec file :

```js
describe('Loading directive', function() {
    ...
    beforeEach(module('/app/directives/loading/templates/loading.html'));
    ...
});
```

I get the following error :

> Failed to instantiate module /app/directives/loading/templates/loading.html due to:
>   Error: No module: /app/directives/loading/templates/loading.html

If I modify the source code of the karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor to print the result of the
generated file, I get :

```js
angular.module('/app/directives/loading/templates/loading.html', []).run(function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('/app/directives/loading/templates/loading.html',
        '<div ng-hide="hideLoading" class="loading_panel">\n' +
        '   <div class="center">\n' +
        '       <div class="content">\n' +
        '           <span ng-transclude></span>\n' +
        '           <canvas width="32" height="32"></canvas>\n' +
        '       </div>\n' +
        '   </div>\n' +
    '</div>');
});
```

So it seems that the generated JS file is correct but not loaded by karma...

Also, if I use --log-level debug, here are the lines related to the template :

> DEBUG [preprocessor.html2js]: Processing "/home/rightink/public_html/bo2/master/web/app/directives/loading/templates/loading.html"
>
> DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
>
> ```js
>       /correct/path/to/the/app/directives/loading/templates/loading.html.js
> ```

Am I missing something ?

Thanks,

Comment: Try to figure out by looking on https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing repository.

Comment: I learned testing AngularJS directive with this repo. So I'm inspired from it since the beginning.

Comment: Have you tried running it in a browser in debug mode and looking at the HTML source? Do you see the .html.js files listed in the script tags?

Answer (score 12):

The problem may be that relative paths specified in `file` section get expanded to full ones.

Something like `directives/loading/templates/loading.html` => `/home/joe/project/angular-app/directives/loading/templates/loading.html`

... and then, templates get registered with theirs full paths.

The solution is to configure the ng-html2js preprocessor to remove the absolute part of the template paths. For instance, in the *karma.conf.js* file add the *stripPrefix* directive like this :

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    // strip this from the file path
    stripPrefix: '.*/project/angular-app/'
    prependPrefix: '/app/'
}
```

Note that stripPrefix is a regexp.

Answer (score 11):

You can have the pre-processor cache your templates to a module, which can then be included prior to your tests:

**karma.conf.js**

```
files: [
  ...
  'app/**/*.html'
],

preprocessors: {
  'app/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
},

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
   moduleName: 'templates'
},
```

**directive file**

```
...
templateUrl: 'app/path-to-your/template.html',
...
```

**spec file**

```
describe('My directive', function() {

  beforeEach(module('templates'));
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This may not be your exact issue, but in our application we needed to add the following to karma.conf.js:

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    cacheIdFromPath: function(filepath) {
        return '/vision/assets/' + filepath;
    }
}
```

The corresponding preprocessors setting looks like:

```
preprocessors: {
    'views/**/*.html': 'html2js'
},
```

My understanding was that this was due to using absolute URLs in AngularJS when specifying templates - which karma was rewriting when running tests?

Anyway hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the process of learning AngularJS and ran into the same problem. I have no idea why but changing the port in karma.conf.js fixed it for me.

```
module.exports = function(config){
  config.set({

    ...

    port: 9877,

    ...

  });
};
```

Edit:

After a bit more testing I found that the problem was only happening on Chrome, and was resolved by explicitly clearing all of the browser history (Ctrl + F5 didn't work).